# how to iterate over certain rows of a certain column an update their value. by applying condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to update the value of opening stock and closing stock by adding 20 when `dcsDep2 < 3.028512`.
 here is the snapshot of dataset:[image]

I tried with this code:

```
for(index_label,row_series) in dep1.iterrows():
    while row_series["Closing Stock"]<3.028512:
            dep1.at[index_label,"Closing Stock"]=row_series["Closing Stock"]+22
```

but no output is shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [df.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to make the selection and then set the values. Take a look at this example and modify according to your dataset.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[0.1,0.3,0.9], 'c':[4,5,6]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   a    b  c
0  1  0.1  4
1  2  0.3  5
2  3  0.9  6

In [4]: df.loc[df['b'] < 0.5, ['a', 'c']] += 20

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
    a    b   c
0  21  0.1  24
1  22  0.3  25
2   3  0.9   6
```

Also, in future try to provide a sample from your dataset as a table of values and not an image so that it becomes easier to reproduce an example.